# Are countable graphs with infinite minimal degree $1$-factorizable?

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

We say that a simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ is *$1$-factorizable* if there is a partition of $E$ such that every member of the partition is a [perfect matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_matching) of $G$. It is easy to see that any $1$-factorizable graph is regular (every vertex has the same degree).

If $G =(\omega, E)$ is a graph on the vertex set $\omega$ such that every vertex has degree $\aleph_0$, does this imply that $G$ is $1$-factorizable?

(It is a [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790407/infinite-graph-g-omega-e-with-deltag-aleph-0-and-no-perfect-matchi) that such a graph has a perfect matching.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cardinality of a set of mutually disjoint perfect matchings of $K_\omega$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336981/cardinality-of-a-set-of-mutually-disjoint-perfect-matchings-of-k-omega). See my answer (not the accepted answer) to that question, in particular the sentence "**More generally,** if $G$ is a countable graph in which each vertex has infinite degree, then $E(G)$ is the union of $\aleph_0$ disjoint perfect matchings."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, any $\aleph_0$-regular graph $G=(V,E)$ is $1$-factorizable. (By "graph" I mean "simple graph" as in the question. Actually a loopless multigraph is OK provided no two vertices are joined by an infinite number of edges.)

Let $C$ be a set of colors, $|C|=\aleph_0$. We will color the edges of $G$ with colors from $C$ so that each vertex is incident with just one edge of each color.

Since each connected component of $G$ is countable, we may assume that $|V|=|E|=\aleph_0$. The coloring will be done in $\omega$ steps, at most one edge being colored at each step, so that at each step only a finite number of edges will have been colored. Fix enumerations $E=\{e_i:i\in\omega\}$ and  $V\times C=\{(v_i,c_i):i\in\omega\}$.

At step $2i$ consider the edge $e_i$. If it has already been colored, do nothing; otherwise, give it a color which has not been given to any edge adjacent to $e_i$.

At step $2i+1$ consider the pair $(v_i,c_i)$. If the vertex $v_i$ is already incident with an edge of color $c_i$, do nothing; otherwise find an edge incident with $v_i$ which has not yet been colored and is not incident with any edge of color $c_i$, and give it the color $c_i$.

It is easy to see that this construction can be carried out, and the resulting coloring has the desired properties.

A similar argument shows that every $\aleph_\alpha$-regular graph is $1$-factorizable.